# archive list with django templatetags

Tags: python, django

I have a django application, a blog. The entries for the blog can be accessed through a /year/month/day/slug url pattern, it works fine.
My problem is, I want to have an archive list accessible to any template on my website. So i thought the best solution would be to create a templatetag that would create and return the info i needed.

I wanted the format of the archive to be as such:

```
August 2011
July 2011
etc..
2010
2009
2008
etc..
```

So only show months for the current year.

This is the tag i came up with:

```
from django.template import Library, Node, TemplateSyntaxError
from core.blog.models import Entry
import datetime, calendar

register = Library()

class ArchiveNode(Node):
    def __init__(self, varname):
        self.varname = varname

    def render(self, context):
        temp = list()

        #Get Info about the first post
        first = Entry.objects.order_by("pub_date")[0]
        first_year = first.pub_date.year
        first_month = first.pub_date.month

        #Loop over years and months since first post was created
        today = datetime.datetime.today()
        this_year = today.year
        this_month = today.month

        for year in range(this_year - first_year):
            if year != this_year:
                temp += (year,'/blog/'+year+'/')
            else:
                for month in range(this_month - first_month):
                    month_name = calendar.month_name[month]
                    temp += (month_name+" "+year,'/blog/'+year+'/'+month+'/')
        context[self.varname] = temp.reverse()
        return ''

@register.tag
def get_archive(parser, token):
    bits = token.contents.split()
    if len(bits) != 3:
        raise TemplateSyntaxError, "get_archive tag takes exactly 1 argument"
    if bits[1] != 'as':
        raise TemplateSyntaxError, "second argument to get_archive tag must be 'as'"
    return ArchiveNode(bits[2])
```

As you can see im returning a list of tuples, containing a name and a url.
Would this be valid in django? or do i need to pack the information in some django container? (It's doen't seem to return anything)

This is the site im working on [ctrl-dev.com/blog](http://ctrl-dev.com/blog).
The archive will be in the green box on the lower right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to return something special. Django is just Python, so it is your choice what you want to return. In this case I would recommend to return dictionary like this (just inventing) `{{'title':'some title if you want','year': 'year if you want', 'url': url}, {...}, ...}`. Then in template you just run through like:

```
{% for entry in returned_dict %}
  <a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Also I would recommend to not hardcode the link in to the code. Read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/ about url resolvers, then https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#url about {% url %} template tag. You can name the urls and later you can get the urls to the stuff you want without hardcoding it in the code. This will help in future ;)

Hope that helped.

Comment: thanks for your reply, helped alot :) Links were great reading, makes sense. Ended up doing like you suggested, return a dict with title, year, month. Then retrieve the URL like this {% url EntryByMonth link.year link.month %}